# OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed trying to use numpy()

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have some `tfrecord` files which I am loading into a `TFRecordDataset` and then trying to pass to `dataset.map`.  There is a lot of data in this dataset, and I am just trying to extract an image and 2D bounding boxes from each record.  I'm using the Waymo dataset and its api for extracting the data.

In order to extract this information using the Waymo API I have to convert the Tensor to a numpy array. I call my map function like this

```
dataset.map(read_tfrecord, num_parallel_calls=4)
```

the mapping function is here

```
@tf.function
def read_tfrecord(example):
  image, true_boxes = tf.py_function(read_tfrecord_np, [example], tf.float32)
  return image, true_boxes
```

My `read_tfrecord_np` function looks like

```
def read_tfrecord_np(example):
    frame = open_dataset.Frame()
    frame.ParseFromString(bytearray(example.numpy()))
    ...
    return front_image, true_boxes
```

Here is the stacktrace

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError:
>   in converted code:   train.py:66 read_tfrecord  *
>       true_boxes, image = tf.py_function(read_tfrecord_np, [example], tf.float32)
>   /home/vagrant/anaconda3/envs/projf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:539
>   **iter**
>       self._disallow_iteration()   /home/vagrant/anaconda3/envs/projf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:532
>   _disallow_iteration
>       self._disallow_when_autograph_enabled("iterating over `tf.Tensor`")
>   /home/vagrant/anaconda3/envs/projf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:510
>   _disallow_when_autograph_enabled
>       " decorating it directly with @tf.function.".format(task))   OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not
>   allowed: AutoGraph did not convert this function. Try decorating it
>   directly with @tf.function.

It says "try decorating it directly with @tf.function" but I am doing that.  What am I doing wrong here?  I'm using tensorflow 2.1.0